# escape special characters while retrieving audio list from external storage

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-audiomanager

I am trying for music player app. I'm able to retrieve all the songs including artists, song name, album name, album cover pictures. But my problem is, after downloading the audio zip files from the website, extracting, the folder name will be automatically saved. Sample file name *ROBO_2(2018)[djmaza.info]*. I'm able to retrieve the songs only If I erase the hiphen(-) or underscore(_) and .info and then saving. Here is code.

```
  public void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = HomeActivity.this.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Bitmap albumcover;

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE));

            retriever.setDataSource(data);
            byte[] cover_pic = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            String album_cover;
            if (cover_pic != null) {
                albumcover = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cover_pic, 0, cover_pic.length);
                album_cover = String.valueOf(albumcover);
            } else {
                albumcover = null;
                album_cover = null;
            }

            if (data.equals("") && title.equals("") && album.equals("") && artist.equals("") && duration.equals("") ||
                    data == null && title == null && album == null && artist == null && duration == null) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You don't have any playlists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new AudioList(data, title, album, artist, duration, albumcover));
            }

        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Help me out with this.

Comment: I see no external storage. I see no zip file. I see no folder. I see no saving. Where is this about? And that file name is of..  what?

Comment: @greenapps.. the above code is for retrieving audio files from external storage. i'm having 40 songs. Suppose one folder name is named as movie_1[mp3.com] under this this 20 songs is there, and movie 2[mp3] folder having 20 songs. I'm able to retrieve songs from movie 2[mp3] folder and not able to retrieve from movie_1[mp3.com], because of the special characters underscore and dot.

Comment: `the above code is for retrieving audio files from external storage`. Nonsense. You are querying the media store. Where the files reside is irrelevant. You should indicate in your code where you have those 'folders' and special file names.

Comment: can you please give another example which gives song data including title, album, artist, song cover pic.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: i know that nothing wrong in my code. but tell me how to escape from those special characters. hipen, underscore, dot.

Comment: Repeat: `You should indicate in your code where you have those 'folders' and special file names.` I dont understand your post.

Comment: @Satish I have the same issue, but alas, people have a reputation here. Talk more of slightest miscomings and less or nothing on the actual issue.